# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout Issues on estimated width for header and cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is my code for the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.

What I want to achieve is the collection view cell should automatically resize based on the content in the cell. Once I refresh the collection view, I'm getting the issue as shown in the video.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jVaFWT6cV8FzBqOF_1HRxzXUBYpPYyTh/view?usp=share_link

I have tried on using these several solutions but still no hope.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/663938
[UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout horizontal, not calculating width of content when using estimated and not horizontally hugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227250/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout-horizontal-not-calculating-width-of-content)
[UICollectionView Compositional Layout - items size not updated properly on iPad rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70733971/uicollectionview-compositional-layout-items-size-not-updated-properly-on-ipad)
[UICollectionViewCell content wrong size on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593117/uicollectionviewcell-content-wrong-size-on-first-load)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For building a tag list, I used this small lib: [AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout)

You can open the repository on GitHub, copy the source file only, and use it in your project for easier customizing.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this for now until I find any solutions.